# Facebook Page / App Perfomance Reporting

Tags: facebook, service, reporting, analytics

i am looking for a solution to this problem:

we regularly have to report to our clients about the facebook apps and pages we are running for them and it is very tedious to always pull the insights from all the single pages and apps, then put them into spreadsheets, build nice graphs and lay it out nicely in a bundled pdf report.

are there any "affordable" solutions that can collect, aggregate and output insights info in a configurable manner? that means i want to select multiple pages and apps, control the specific fields that are included in reports and have that conveniently delivered to me as a pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the report generator, such as Fast Reports. It can be used together with your application, which will collect the necessary information. Reports can be exported to PDF.